# Writing query for different months

Tags: javascript, oracle

I am trying to make a graph that shows company's total sale per day. That is my query to find today's total sale:

```
select count(*) from registered_devices where  status = 1;
```

and this is the query to find total sale in 7 days ago:

```
 select count(*) from registered_devices where sysdate - 7 <TO_DATE('19700101','yyyymmdd') + ((create_time)/1000/24/60/60) and status = 1;
```

I want to take each day's total sale value and put them on an Highcharts graph. But as you know, some months have 31 and the others have 30 days, so I can't write query for each day seperately. Can you help me with this? How can I write query for each day of a month, regarding that each month have different number of days? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use `TO_CHAR()` and aggregate on the day:

```
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(create_time, 'yyyy/mm/dd'),
    COUNT(*)
FROM registered_devices
WHERE status = 1
GROUP BY
    TO_CHAR(create_time, 'yyyy/mm/dd')
```

One caveat here is that the above query will not output a given day if it had no activity whatsoever.  If you want to guarantee to always show every day, you could create a calendar table.

Also, you can limit the date range by adding another condition to the `WHERE` clause which checks `create_time`.

Comment: I get this error from OraExp:  "DATE_FORMAT": invalid identifier , what is the reason?

Comment: Are you using Oracle?  Why did you tag with MySQL?

Comment: It was reccomended so I didn't notice. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: So how can I edit this to use in Oracle? Thank you @Tim

Comment: Thanks but I get error, it says FROM keyword not found where expected. I tried different combinations but I couldn't managed. Can you look at it again? Thank you.

Comment: There was a missing comma, that's all.

Comment: I get error again, on the last line, it says invalid number format model and makes the first apostrophe of the last line red. I tried 'DD-Mon-YYYY' format but I get the same error. I didn't understand the reason.

Comment: Is `create_time` a date column?  You didn't store your dates as text, did you?

Comment: I did it using counter_date. This is my code, if somebody else needs it    `code` SELECT
TO_CHAR(counter_date, 'DD-Mon-YYYY' ) ,
COUNT(*) as FROM statistics  
GROUP BY
TO_CHAR(counter_date, 'DD-Mon-YYYY' ) `code`    Thanks @Tim for your kindness and help! :)

Comment: This comment won't help anyone, because you never even mentioned the `counter_date` column in your question.